Flutter Post Request Do Not Send Body Parameters
My flutter Post request is not sending the parameters to server. Whenever I check for the variables from the server I see NULL. I have tried a lot of options and I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code:
Future<void> listRecentCashTransactions() async{
 try{
   var res = await http.post(
       Uri.parse(API.recentCashTransactionURL),
       body: {
           'userID': userID.toString(),
           'sessionData': sessionData.toString(),
       },
   );
   if(res.statusCode==200){
       final resBody = jsonDecode(res.body);
       final sessionDataX = resBody['checkSessionData'];
       int userXID = resBody['checkUserID'];

       print("User ID before API call : $userID");
       print("User ID after API call : $userXID");
       print("Session Data before API call : $sessionData");
       print("Session data after : $sessionDataX");
   }   
 }
 catch(e){
   print(e.toString());
 }
}


Try to use jsonEncode to encode the request body as JSON like... body: jsonEncode({
'userID': userID.toString(),
'sessionData': sessionData.toString(),
}),
And add headers... headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},

To solve the issue of sending parameters in a POST request, it is better to serialize the data to JSON and set the appropriate headers. Here's how you can modify your code to use JSON serialization:
import 'dart:convert';

Future<void> listRecentCashTransactions() async {
      try {
        final requestData = {
            'userID': userID.toString(),
           'sessionData': sessionData.toString(),
        };

        final res = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(API.recentCashTransactionURL),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: jsonEncode(requestData),
        );
    
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
          final resBody = jsonDecode(res.body);
          final sessionDataX = resBody['checkSessionData'];
          int userXID = resBody['checkUserID'];
    
          print("User ID before API call: $userID");
          print("User ID after API call: $userXID");
          print("Session Data before API call: $sessionData");
          print("Session data after: $sessionDataX");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
      }
    }


So how do I receive it on the backend. Can I do something like this:
$_POST['userID'] and $_POST['sessionData'].

yes like that you could also use my sqli escape string to avoid SQL Injection here's an example :
$userID= mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['userID']);
the $connect is your DB connection variable
